# Boost::thread crashes during simple loop

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

I am trying out some simple `boost::thread` code, as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

void InputLoop()
{
    std::cout << "Loop start" << std::endl;

    int y = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        std::cout << "y = " << y << std::endl;
        y++;
    }

    std::cout << "Loop end" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Main start" << std::endl;

    boost::thread t(InputLoop);
    t.start_thread();

    while (1)
    {
        int x = 0;
    }

    std::cout << "Main end" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

This gives the output:

```
Main start
Loop start
y = 0
y = 1
y = 2
.
.
.
The program has unexpectedly finished
```

So, it is crashing during `InputLoop()`. The value of `y` when the crash occurs varies between different runs, and ranges from about 0 to about 10000.

What's going on?

Comment: It runs on http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/. Though, without t.start_thread(); and with "warning: unused variable 'x' [-Wunused-variable] int x = 0;"

Comment: Either I need to upgrade or downgrade my boost-pick. Because `start_thread` claims `private` access permission on my platform (OSX 10.7.1)

Comment: @WhozCraig - Sorry, edited, forgot to mention - "/usr/local/include/boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp:177:14: error: 'void boost::thread::start_thread()' is private void start_thread()". Just wanted to point that it doesn't "crash unexpectedly".

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't call start_thread?

This is not required, as it's a leaked internal implementation detail:

- https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/9632

> In my code I accidentally called this method and it resulted in my callback being started twice.

So you get unsynchronized access to `std::cout`, `y` which leads to **[Undefined Behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)**

The fix is found in this commit: https://github.com/boostorg/thread/commit/750c849b0f0dff79a289111955260a4147ac7f59

Answer (score 0):

Even though there **is** a public method `start_thread` in `class thread`, it isn't in the [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.thread). That's for a [reason](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/doc/html/thread/thread_management.html#thread.thread_management.tutorial.launching):

> ## Launching threads
>
> A new thread is launched by passing an object of a callable type that can be invoked with no parameters to the constructor. [...]
>
> If you wish to construct an instance of boost::thread with a function or callable object that requires arguments to be supplied, this can be done by passing additional arguments to the boost::thread constructor:

Regardless which constructor you use, the thread is already running:

```
// <boost/thread/detail/thread.hpp>
template <
  class F
>
explicit thread(BOOST_THREAD_RV_REF(F) f
//, typename disable_if<is_same<typename decay<F>::type, thread>, dummy* >::type=0
):
  thread_info(make_thread_info(thread_detail::decay_copy(boost::forward<F>(f))))
{
    start_thread();
}
```

How's `start_thread` defined?

```
void start_thread()
{
  if (!start_thread_noexcept())
  {
    boost::throw_exception(thread_resource_error());
  }
}
```

`start_thread_noexcept` is actually not in a header, but part of `libboost_thread`:

```
// boost/lib/thread/src/thread.cpp
bool thread::start_thread_noexcept()
{
    thread_info->self=thread_info;
    int const res = pthread_create(&thread_info->thread_handle, 0, &thread_proxy, thread_info.get());
    if (res != 0)
    {
        thread_info->self.reset();
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

You actually created two threads. And it's (probably) the `thread_proxy` implementation that creates your behaviour.